# How to run the django-admin manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django-admin, django-runserver

I just want to call this command : `django-admin manage.py runserver` but it always fails and it gives me this message instead:

```
(No Django settings specified. Unknown command: 'manage.py')
```

what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The real command is:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

your version with django is incorrect.
django-admin using for creating project

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where your `manage.py` file is located nad run
`./manage.py runserver` or `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

You must either define the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` or call `settings.configure()` before accessing settings.
After that's enough to run the below command for running the project:

```bash
➜ django-admin runserver
```

or run the below command in the base directory of project:

```bash
➜ python manage.py runserver
```